# Как пополнить баланс на своем сайте через webmoney

Tags: php, webmoney

Хочу подключить webmoney для пополнения баланса на своем сайте, но не знаю какой интерфейс нужен. И структура api webmoney тоже не понятно. Пожалуйста помогите.

Comment: У меня тоже встал такой вопрос. Вы решили? Вы имели ввиду пополнение баланса телефона через АПИ Вебмани?

Comment: Да я подключил merchant но только для пополнения баланса сайта, а не телефона.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения вашей задачи вполне подойдет Web Merchant Interface. 
Как именно его реализовать - достаточно подробно описано в кратком и подробном руководстве.
https://merchant.webmoney.ru/conf/default.asp